# Incomplete parsing of Pinterest using urllib, requests and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pinterest, urllib3

I have tried parsing the following Pinterest page using urllib, requests, and chromedriver:

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/463237511669606028/

But it looks like some sections of the page are missing in my result. Specifically, I'm trying to parse the number of re-pins (below the comments), which I can't.

I have tried both of these options but userActivity class is not part of what I get:

```
driver.get("https://www.pinterest.com/pin/463237511669606028/")
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
```

and

```
req = urllib2.Request("https://www.pinterest.com/pin/463237511669606028/", 
headers={'User-Agent': "PyBrowser"}) 
con = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content = con.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,features="html.parser")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: its likely dynamic content that is rendered after the pageload.

Comment: In that case, I can write a script for chromedriver to scroll down and wait a little bit for the content to load. But the problem is that, on a large scale, it's not feasible. Is there a way to load a larger part of the page without doing that?

Comment: @Shayan Which `re-pins` exactly which are `below the comments`?

Comment: @DebanjanB the number next to pin symbol. In this case, the number is "95". I'm also interested in this line: "Christine Ringo Christine Ringo saved to Dinner Recipes". Note that I can do it with webdriver. But I hope to see if I can do it with BeautifulSoup, since it takes less time. My guess is that with BeuatifuSoup you are not logged in, so you don't have access to certain data.